# Woocommerce payment_complete hook alternative

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, payment-gateway, hook-woocommerce

We do an API call to a partner to place an order for one of their services as soon as we receive a payment. We use the payment complete hook to do so but the issue is that it only fires with our Stripe gateway and not with off site payment providers such as Paypal, here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'apicall_create' );
function apicall_create( $order_id ) {
        $_present = WC()->session->get('_created');
        if ($_present === "1") {
        $data_creation = WC()->session->get('data_');
        $call_create = callAPI('POST', 'https://dojo-production-api.production.cluster.io/v1/ancillary/', json_encode($data_creation));
        $response_create = json_decode($call_create, true);
        update_post_meta( $order_id, '_contract', $response_create);
        WC()->session->__unset('_qover');
        WC()->session->__unset('_created');
        }
    
}
```

Which other hooks can we use that would be fired no matter the gateway, the thankyou hook seems to be an option but won't it risked being fired twice on customer refresh or just not at all if people leave before the thank you page?

More precisely is there a hook that is fired when the order is created for good and the payment has been processed and accepted and woocommerce receives that information as it seems that payment_complete only works in certain cases.

Thank you!

Comment: Would woocommerce_pre_payment_complete be a better option?

Comment: Sorry but `woocommerce_payment_complete` fires with all gateways (including All Paypal payment methods) on successful payments (except cheque and Bank wire). So there is something else that is making trouble in your case.

Comment: No `woocommerce_pre_payment_complete` is not a good option as there is no confirmation yet and nor transaction ID yet.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the action hook `woocommerce_order_status_completed` triggered when order status is "completed", that has 2 arguments `$order_id` and `$order`.

Comment: Ok thank you, order status completed would not work as the orders default to processing before we ship the items. What could be preventing payment complete from triggering after payment complete